# Can a controller manage more than one model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I want my controller to put `modelA` into `viewA` and `modelB` into `viewB`.

From what I know a controller can be associated with only one view using only one model.

Correct me please if I'm wrong.

Comment: no. One action is associated with one view and one model. Controller can manage any number of views or models

Comment: @Anubhav: Why one model? You can have one model in the whole application, don't you?

Comment: he used *a controller* and *only one view* and *only one model* in same sentence

Comment: @Anubhav Saini, do you have an example link?

Comment: It's a ViewModel there's only one, your ViewModel has NO correlation to your persistence models. Your View Model represents the data on the View. If your view displays data from multiple Persistence Models then you need to compose them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want my controller to put modelA into viewA and modelB into viewB.

BO classes:

```
class modelA{
...
}
class modelB{
...
}
```

Controller code:

```
...other using statements...
using MyProj.DAL;
using MyProj.BO;

public class MyController:Controller
{
//Create object of your Data Access Layer's MyDAL functionality
MyDAL DALobj = new MyDAL();


public ActionResult viewAList(){
modelA mobj = DALobj.FetchObjFromDB();
return View(mobj);
}

public ActionResult viewACreate(modelA newobj){
...check if modelstate is okay and tweak your model object here...
DALobj.SendDataToDB(newobj);
return RedirectToView("some other view | index");
}


public ActionResult viewBList(){
...same as viewAList() but with modelB this time...
}

public ActionResult viewBCreate(){
...same as viewACreate() but with modelB this time...
}
}//controller ends here
```

I guess what is asked is:

> From what I know a controller can be associated with only one view
>   using only one model.

I translate it as :

1. There can be only one view consuming one model associated with a particular controller.

which I think looks like this:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
      static List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View(people);
      }
      public ActionResult Details(Person person)
      {
          return View(person);
      }
      public ActionResult Create()
      {
          return View();
      } 
      [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
      public ActionResult Create(Person person)
      {
          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
          {
              return View("Create", person);
          }
          people.Add(person);
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
  }
```

Here is one controller, four Actions, one model. So, One Controller is associated with one model, but not only view (which you can get; by removing any other two Functionalities(not functions, Create-functionality has two functions, one for GET & POST each))

Now, question arises, can you use multiple models in 1 controller?

Answer: Yes. I just showed it in first code example.

Question: Can there be two+ models in 1 controller?

Answer: yes. Create a wrapper model, put other two models in it. and BAM!

How?

(Of course. sigh!)

MODEL | BO:

```
public class BigObjClass{

public A a; 
public B b;

}

public class A{
public int serial{get;}
public int age{get;set;}
}

public class B{
public string Name{get;}
public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

Now, as in very first code example, use `BigObjClass`'s object and pass it to the views.

Please let me know if any of this makes sense to you.

Comment: I have tried to run visual studio sample asp.net mvc projet. still don't get where is the regostration of a view to an controller-action is done?

Answer (score 3):

A Controller-action can only produce 1 View at a time.

But it is possible to build some conditional logic into the Controller and decide which View(s) to 
show.

> a controller can be associated with only one view using only one model

No, a CRUD controller normally associates with 1 Model and produces List/Edit/Delete/Create Views.
So multiple Views is quite normal, so is multiple ViewModels. And a ViewModel often combines information form more than 1 Model entity.

Comment: AccountController uses Register & LogOn model and 4 views. Are you talking about Action being able to use single model? but then you can create a wrapper model and add other models to it. so more models.

Comment: @Anubhav - quite right, good example. But Register and Logon are ususally called ViewModels. They are indeed like wrappers.

Comment: I think you mean *A Controller-action and only return 1 View at a time.*  Returning Json, I have controllers produce multiple views and return them in my Json response.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, do you have an example link? I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: @EladBenda - just crreate a new project with the default template and study the Account controller + views + models

Comment: @Henk Holterman I have tried. still don't get where is the regostration of a view to an controller-action is done?

Comment: Because there is no such registration. The default mapping is entirely on Action-name == View-name, but you can also do `return View("OtherViewName");`